# PHP mssql_query delete, create and select from #temp table

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I am trying to:

1. Delete a temp table if it exists.
2. Create a temp table with a selected data.
3. Select from the temp table.

I am getting "Parse error: parse error in `C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php` on line 57.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Short Info:

- PHP Version 5.2.9
- MS SQL 2008 R2
- The queries executed in MS SQL work as expected

The PHP code below:

```
$query = "IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp"
$result = mssql_query($query);

$query = "
SELECT *
INTO #temp
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY key
      ORDER BY moment desc) AS Seq, *
FROM  reportstable) t
WHERE Seq = 1
and moment between '$_GET[od] $time' and '$_GET[do] $time1'"
$result = mssql_query($query);

$query = "select * from #temp"
$result = mssql_query($query);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which line is line 57?

Comment: mysql is completely removed from php 7 and deprecated php 5.5 and above so avoid using this, use mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 0):

This will not work as written, for a couple reasons.

1. Temp tables as you're using them here are local only to the current session. In other words, `#temp` is disappearing after *each* of your calls to `mssql_query()`. If you need a temp table to persist across multiple contexts, it has to be a global temp table - `##temp`.
2. Your code is *wide open* to SQL injection - you're using unsanitized input from the users. This is a massive security vulnerability that has existed for 2 decades and you're persisting it. Read up on PDO and parameterized queries/prepared statements.
3. Your query is *probably* malformed. Output the *actual* `$query` after constructing it and make sure that your datetime is properly formatted.

All that said, and assuming you fix your SQL injection vulnerability, the use of a temp table here is pointless and wasting resources. The following would be sufficient:

```
$query = "
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY key
      ORDER BY moment desc) AS Seq, *
FROM  reportstable) t
WHERE Seq = 1
and moment between '$_GET[od] $time' and '$_GET[do] $time1'"
$result = mssql_query($query);
```

Comment: Hi,i tried the simplest - create the temp through mssql studio and simply do a select from php without success. I also tried the glibal temp ##. Also without success. Any idea what might be the issue?

Comment: @SpiroK eliminate the temp tables entirely and reduce your code to **only** what I posted here. And output `$query` so that you can see the *actual* query being sent to SQL Server. I suspect that this query is being constructed improperly and that is causing your problems.

Comment: I got it right. The echo $query showed me I was making problem there - missing ; at the end of the query statement. Now I can delete a temp table if it exists, create a temp table and query from the temp table. What I noticed thou, the mssql_fetch_array and mssql_num_rows is not functioning - throws an error "supplied argument is not a valid MS SQL-result resource", thou if I loop through it I can count it and also echo each row.

Answer (score 0):

A working solution based on [alroc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1324345/alroc) suggestions:

The parse error was thrown due to missing semi-colon. And ## must be present at all times in order to be able to query the table.

```
// to delete the temp table
$query = "IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##temp";
$result = mssql_query($query);

// to initialize the temp table
$query = "
SELECT *
INTO ##temp
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY test_key
      ORDER BY test_moment desc) AS Seq, *
FROM  reports_table) t
WHERE Seq = 1
and test_moment between '$_GET[od] $time' and '$_GET[do] $time1'";
$result = mssql_query($query);

// to query the temp table
select test_key
from ##temp
where x = 0
and y = 1
and z = 3
```

p.s. The above works in the same session only. If u call the same page in the same time from different sources, one will throw an error because of trying to drop the temp table.